# Volley RequestQueue Unknown Class?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to implement a simple JsonObjectRequest with Volley.  Everything seems to be working fine until I try to add the request to the queue, in which I get an "unknown class" error.  I figure it has to be something simple, but I'm banging my head.  What gives?

```
public void authGetRequest() {

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);  // this = context

// prepare the Auth Get Request
JsonObjectRequest lastFMAuthRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, lastFMKeyURL, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // display response
                Log.d("Response", response.toString());
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
            }
        }
);

// add it to the RequestQueue
queue.add(lastFMAuthRequest);
```

This is solved. After looking over the code, I figured out that the queue.add(lastFMAuthRequest); was in the wrong spot.  Thx!

Comment: try clean your project, your code seems okay.

Comment: That's what I thought too.  I've cleaned it a bunch of times (File/Invalidate Caches) and nothing new.

Comment: Try to untick private libraries and clean the project and run it again

Comment: Hrm, where might that be?  Can't seem to find it.

Comment: Inside the build path.

Comment: I don't see a spot to check or uncheck private libraries anywhere in IntelliJ.  Just switched to IDEA, so I'm not totally familiar with it yet.  Can you walk me through where this option is?  Sorry/thx!