# queue is unknown in android class

Tags: android, queue, android-volley

[Volley RequestQueue Unknown Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922825/volley-requestqueue-unknown-class)

That doesn't work for me. The volley-build is an extra block. So there is app and volley. Is this correct? It seems that the class queue is unknown.

```
package com.monchsoftware.planer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static void Sende() {

        String url = "http://localhost/php_test_neuer_user.php";
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // response
                        Log.d("Response", response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error
                        String response = "";
                        Log.d("Error.Response", response);
                    }
                }
        )
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", "test@test.com");
                params.put("name", "asd");
                params.put("telephone", "asd");

                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(postRequest);

    }
}
```

How to "import" queue?

Comment: It looks like you're just using `queue` without creating it first.

Comment: You're right. It has to be created like RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context); Solved